# How do I write a regex in java which allow only numbers 0-9 and #

Tags: java, regex

I want the user to input only numbers 0-9 and '#'
No spaces, no alphabets and no other special characters.

For ex:

```
12736#44426 :true
263 35# :false
2376shdbj# :false
 3623t27# :false
#? :false
```

Here's my code:

```
boolean valid(String str)
    {
        if(str.matches("[0-9]+|(\\#)"))
        return true;

        else

        return false;

    }
```

But it returns false for `3256#`

I also tried `[0-9]+|(#)`

I am very noob at regular expressions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tell me if i am not clear.

Comment: How about [`^[0-9#]+|$`](http://regex101.com/r/tR2aP4/1)?

Comment: @AmalMurali: this solves my prob. upto an extent but not completely. It returns true for ` 33` i.e. space before 33

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you create a regex101 demo that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: FYI there are online regex testers for Java to  easily verify the answers here. Here's one: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^[\d#]+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xS8pJ6/1)**

[image]

The idea is to match digits and symbol # by using using the pattern `[\d#]` and can be many 1 or many times (using `+`). And to ensure that the line starts and ends with those characters I use anchors `^` (start of the line) and `$` (end of line).

For java remember to escape backslahes as:

```
^[\\d#]+$
```

The **java** code you can use can be:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\\d#]+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(YOUR TEXT HERE);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("matches!");
}
```

Or also:

```
if ("YOUR STRING HERE".matches("^[\\d#]+$")) {
    System.out.println("matches!");
}
```

If you want to know more about the usage you can check this link:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regexjava

Comment: may I use `^[\\d#]+$` instead ?? Eclipse shows an error `Invalid escape sequence`

Comment: @newbie as I put in the answer. You have to escape backslashes, so for `\d` you have to use `\\d`

Answer (score 4):

Add the `#` character to your character class instead of using the alternation operator.

```
[0-9#]+
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this allows spaces as in  `33 33`

Comment: Hi @hwnd, what happened with your tool? I tried to use it but is offline http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl

Comment: Duh! yes! I wrote scan.next() instead of scan.nextLine(). Thanks for your answer.. easiest of all! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
^[0-9#]+$
```

Try this.This will give you your results.

Comment: this solves my prob. upto an extent but not completely. It returns `true` for ` 33` i.e. space before 33 and true also for `33 33`

Comment: @newbie " 33" is failing.See the link given by me.

Comment: Duh! yes! I wrote `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()`